# How to ignore a folder in git

Tags: git, openshift

I have a Laravel application, it's pushed to OpenShift by Git and I need to tell Git to ignore and not touch public/uploads folder on the server. This folder is created by Laravel (PHP) and with every push, git will delete that ...

Comment: so this folder is in source control? have you looked at the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: it's ignored and git won't upload it ... but it delete this folder from server, I beed to keep it

Answer (score 5):

In your `.gitignore` file add the line

```
public/uploads
```

Comment: Did it before, I don't know why it doesn't work !! it ignores on local I need something to ignore it on server

Comment: You probably did a commit and push BEFORE you put it in .gitignore so it is not going to delete it from the server. I would move it out of the git repo, do a git commit then a git push. Then add it back and do the git commit git push but make sure the line is still in the .gitignore

Comment: Yeah it can be but i'm searching for something like .gitignoreonserver  !!! is it possible to do something like this ?

Comment: If you want to be sure that everything is removed from version control run `git rm -r --cached public/uploads`. Then commit and push. If this does not work, you will have to remove the files manually from the server using a tool like ftp or ssh.